# Webpack relative paths to files and multi slash paths in routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, routes

Recently i encountered an issue with building multi slash routing paths for my react application configured with webpack and nodejs on the backend.

Issue started when i created following path inside routing:

```
// header
{[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((id) => (
    <NavLink to={`/product/${id}`} className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? 'active' : undefined)} key={`product-${id}`}>
        Product
        {id}
    </NavLink>
))}

// router
<Routes>
    <Route path="/product/:id" element={<Product />} />
</Routes>
```

The path itself is working correctly when accessed via link but when accessed from nodejs (refresh or type url directly) it is failing because its trying to load `js` and `css` files with following paths:

- `Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/product/js/main.2265f70c.js'`
- `Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/product/css/style.2265f70c.css'`

So its trying to load `css` and `js` relative to `/products` path.

My webpack config:

```
const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
    template: './src/index.html',
    filename: 'index.html',
});

const miniCssExtractPlugin = new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: 'css/style.[fullhash:8].css',
    chunkFilename: 'css/[id].style.[fullhash:8].css',
});

module.exports = {
    ...
    output: {
        filename: 'js/main.[fullhash:8].js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            ...
            {
                test: /\.(json)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                type: 'javascript/auto',
                options: {
                    name: 'translations/[name].[ext]',
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                type: 'asset',
                generator: {
                    filename: 'assets/[name].[hash][ext]',
                },
                parser: {
                    dataUrlCondition: {
                        maxSize: 20 * 1024, // 20kb
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: {
            rewrites: [{ from: /^\/$/, to: '/index.html' }],
        },
    },
};
```

my nodejs dev server:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const config = require('./config');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist'), {
    maxage: '30d',
}));

app.use('*', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html')));

app.listen(config.port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on :${config.port}`);
});
```

My first idea was to replace relative paths with absolute ones in webpack configuration but that action causes this error:

```
[webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.output.filename: A relative path is expected. However, the provided value "/js/main.[fullhash:8].js" is an absolute path!
Please use output.path to specify absolute path and output.filename for the file name.
```

What is the proper way / good practice of dealing with it, so multi slash url is just virtual and not actually / literally considered?

- nodejs v16.15.0
- webpack v5.74.0
- react v18.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i was able to solve the problem by modifying webpack `output` configuratoin:

```
output: {
    publicPath: '/', // this is the fix
    filename: 'js/main.[fullhash:8].js'
},
```

After adding `publicPath: '/'` it started to work properly (files are loaded from root, while virtual locations are routed correctly)